# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate'

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I have following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and following source code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class ArApplication {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ArApplication.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("robotCommand", "test");

    }    
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

}
```

And my application could not start:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1092)
    at pack.ArApplication.main(ArApplication.java:34)
```

What the reason?

Comment: I don't think simply adding `@EnableJms` exposes JmsTemplate automatically. You actually need to define the bean in the first place. Have you got any other configurations or is this it?

Comment: @Setu, I don't see any additional configurations here https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/

Comment: Apologies I stand corrected and thanks for the link. Just noticed in the code your class name is `ArApplication` while the context you are obtaining is using `Application`. is this typo or you have different Application classes?

Comment: @Setu it is root cause thanks

Comment: @gstackoverflow can you delete your question then? It is flagged as being unanswered here so folks are losing their time looking at your question for nothing.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Boot, this error may be caused by using activemq-pool, support for which was [dropped in version 2.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#activemq-pooling). It was replaced by pooled-jms.

The following dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

should be replaced with:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.messaginghub</groupId>
    <artifactId>pooled-jms</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added to my test class:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc()
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MusicPlayerApplication.class)
```

**@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
classes = Server.class)**

```
class DecoratorQueueServiceTest {
}
```